# How to pass in operators to SQL from NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

In my NodeJS app, I want the user to be able to pass in a filter into a mySQL (v8.0.20) query (using Knex):

`const sql = 'SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE id = ? AND ?? ? ?';`

The series of question marks at the end is where I want to add in the filter, e.g. id > 3. I know one question mark indicates a value and two indicates an attribute/table name. But neither work for <,>,=. How do I tell SQL that this is a built-in operator?

Comment: MySQL (and pretty much all other RDBMS) do not support the parameterisation of _operators_, only values. You'll need to use Dynamic SQL (which is _dangerously unsafe_ or a library that lets you compose queries (better!) and a rules-engine-UI to allow you users to compose them.

Comment: Also, "NodeJS API" isn't a thing. There are _many_ database libraries for NodeJS - please be specific about the libraries you're using and the version of MySQL that you're using.

Comment: Ok thank you! I'll be more clear in the future :)

Comment: @firehazard is this the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) you are using?

Comment: yeah I think so @rags2riches, this problem is more or less solved though! project supervisor pulled though

Answer (score 0):

You can't use parameters to supply structural parts of an SQL query. Parameters are meant to be value placeholders.

If you scrutinize the user-supplied field names and operators properly, you can build the SQL query dynamically. Keep the `?` for user-supplied values.

```js
const allowedOperators = ['=', '>', '>=', '<', '<=', '!='];
const allowedFields = ['id', 'name', 'etc'];

if (
    allowedOperators.indexOf(userSuppliedOperator) > -1 && 
    allowedFields.indexOf(userSuppliedField.toLowerCase()) > -1
) {
    var sql = `SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE id = ? AND {userSuppliedField} {userSuppliedOperator} ?`;
    // use SQL string
} else {
    throw new Error("Invalid search parameters");
}
```